# How can I increase the size of twitter bootstrap carousel navigation arrows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I increase the size of twitter bootstrap navigation icon arrows found here?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

I have tried increasing the width/height property in the following css to 70px from 30px but this did not work

```
prev, .carousel-control .icon-next {
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
font-size: 30px;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's a `font` so all you need to do is make it bigger

for example:

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, 
.carousel-control .icon-next {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

then use `margin-top` to adjust the horizontal position, for example (in case of `100px` in `font-size`) use `margin-top: -70px;`

[image]

Comment: This is true, but also a bit tricky. Might not look identical in all browsers. The line-height and icon-fonts are a bit off in different browsers, even with adjusted margins.